# Google Analytics ga.js keeps changing for each request - why?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, request, switch-statement

If you keep on refreshing https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js you will notice that the contents keeps switching between two versions. One starting with:

```
function(){var s=true,t=false,aa=window,u=undefined,v=Math,ba="push",fa="slice",ga="cookie",y="charAt",z="indexOf",A="gaGlobal",ha="getTime",ja="toString",B="window",D="length
```

and the other

```
(function(){var aa="_gat",ba="_gaq",r=true,v=false,w=undefined,ca=document,da="4.7.2",y="length",z="cookie",A="location",ea="_gaUserPrefs",fa="ioo",B="&",C="=",D="__utma=",
```

Update:

I can see that one file contains `da="4.7.2"` and the other one contains `na="4.8.6"`. It looks like different versions numbers.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. There was a change happening. Google was slowly releasing a new version (4.8.6), and you must have been caught at some sort of weird mid-release point.

[From GA's Release Notes:](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/changelog.html#release-2010-10)

> **Release 2010-10 (October 4, 2010)**
>
> This release contains regular
>   maintenance including bug fixes and
>   refactorings. There is no change to
>   the public APIs or functionality.

Because of the nature and size of Google's servers, this sort of change takes a long time to push out.

Ibid:

> Note that you and your users may not
>   see the updated ga.js right away
>   because: Changes are incrementally
>   rolled out over several days across
>   Google's global data center
>   infrastructure. Users of your website
>   may temporarily have older versions of
>   our javascript cached in their
>   browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this.
Check your proxy configuration; you may have a bad cache.

Comment: I press CTRL+R in firefox - the same browser all the time - and it keeps changing. That cant be the cache, can it?

Comment: I even check this via a Java-application which is getting two different files all the time.

Comment: You may have an upstream proxy with a bad cache.

Comment: I have just tried it on another computer with another network and isp, same problem - you should have the same problem too.

Comment: No, I don't.  It could be that I have a bad cache, but I don't think I'm behind an SSL proxy.

Comment: The normal url http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js keeps changing as well. Can I ask how your starts? Is it s=true or aa="_gat"?

Comment: They mostly both start with `var s=true,t=false,`.  The first time I loaded the non-HTTPS one, it started with `aa="_gat"`; every other time, it started with `var s=true,t=false,`.

Comment: So it changes, even for you. Obviously :-)